# Drawing a tree diagram

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to draw a tree diagram, like this

[image]

I use Wolfram do some work

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
(*=== data ===*)
data1 = 1;
data2 = Range[2, 6, 1];
data3 = Range[7, 9, 1];

(*=== vertex ===*)

verColor = {1 -> Orange, # -> RGBColor["#c6d8ed"] & /@ 
     data2, # -> RGBColor["#a0b88b"] & /@ data3} // Flatten;

(*=== edge ===*)
edge1 = DirectedEdge[data1, #] & /@ data2;
edge2 = Array[DirectedEdge, {5, 3}, {{2, 6}, {7, 9}}] // Flatten;
edge = {edge1, edge2} // Flatten;

(*=== graph ===*)
Graph[edge,
 (*-- vertex --*)
 VertexSize -> 0.7,
 VertexStyle -> verColor,
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle",
 (*-- edge --*)
 EdgeStyle -> {Arrowheads[2]},
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "Arrow"]
```

[image]

as you can see,There are many defects.

- arrow not in center
  [image]
- arrowhead too large,it seem can not change it size
  [image]

what should I do？

Comment: To change the size of the arrowηheads, use this: `Column@(Graph[edge, ImageSize -> 500,
     (*--vertex--*)VertexSize -> 0.7, VertexStyle -> verColor, 
     VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle",
     (*--edge--*)EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[#], 
     EdgeShapeFunction -> 
      GraphElementData["FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> #], 
     GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"}] & /@ {.03, .04, .05})`